# CSS. Не работает отступ

Tags: html, css

не работает отступ у background у элементов списка.
Что делать?

```css
.mobile_list li {
  background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/15x15/33ff99/555555?text=Png') left no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 2;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: left;
  color: #8c8c8c;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mobile_list">
  <li>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option;</li>
  <li>Option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer;</li>
  <li>Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum futurum; </li>
  <li>Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: попробуйте вынести left в отдельное background-position

Comment: О каком отступе идёт речь? Если вы о background: **left** - то никакого отступа не будет, ибо left = 0, а 0 позиция по умолчанию.

Comment: Речь идёт об отступе между значком(background) и самим текстом. Как мне сделать отступ между ними?

Comment: li padding-left 50px

Comment: Cпасибо большое